# WPF DataTrigger using enum fails

Tags: c#, wpf, enums, datatrigger

**The case:**

I have a customized `ToggleButton` that uses a `DrawingImage` to draw a hexagon to use as template background making it a hexagonally shaped toggle button.

I want to change the color (`Brush`) and border (`Pen`) of the drawing so the button looks different for different purposes.

There’s a couple of conditions that’s taken into consideration when deciding what color should be used, and what I’ve tried so far is having a `DependencyProperty` and a `DataTrigger` in the hex button style to select the correct `DrawingImage` (from a `ResourceDictionary`). The `DependencyProperty` is being set to the correct value so that part of the code works the way it should. The problem is that the `DataTrigger` doesn’t seem to do anything. I'm sure I've missed something silly, I just can't see what it is...

I’ve made a simplified example to demonstrate my problem, and here’s some of the code:

**HexButton**

```
public class HexButton : ToggleButton
{
    public enum HexBackground
    {
        Default,
        Red,
        RedHover,
        RedChecked,
        RedCheckedHover,
        // etc...
    }

    public HexBackground CurrentBackground
    {
        get { return (HexBackground)GetValue(CurrentBackgroundProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CurrentBackgroundProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentBackgroundProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "CurrentBackground",
        typeof(HexBackground),
        typeof(HexButton),
        new PropertyMetadata(HexBackground.Default)
        );

    /* removed some code to avoid too much wall of text */
}
```

**Resources**

```
<DrawingImage x:Key="HexRed">
    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
        <DrawingGroup>
            <GeometryDrawing Brush="Red" Geometry="M 25,0 L 75,0 L 100,43 L 75,86 L 25,86 L 0,43 Z">
                <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                    <Pen Brush="Black" Thickness="2" LineJoin="Round"/>
                </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
            </GeometryDrawing>
        </DrawingGroup>
    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
</DrawingImage>
<DrawingImage x:Key="HexRedHover">
    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
        <DrawingGroup>
            <GeometryDrawing Brush="DarkRed" Geometry="M 25,0 L 75,0 L 100,43 L 75,86 L 25,86 L 0,43 Z">
                <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                    <Pen Brush="Black" Thickness="6" LineJoin="Round"/>
                </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
            </GeometryDrawing>
        </DrawingGroup>
    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
</DrawingImage>
```

**Style**

```
<Style x:Key="HexButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type hex:HexButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type hex:HexButton}">
                <Grid>
                    <Image x:Name="img" Source="{StaticResource HexDefault}"/>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CurrentBackground}" Value="{x:Static hex:HexButton+HexBackground.Red}">
                        <Setter TargetName="img" Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource HexRed}"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CurrentBackground}" Value="{x:Static hex:HexButton+HexBackground.RedHover}">
                        <Setter TargetName="img" Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource HexRedHover}"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <!--<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="img" Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource HexRedHover}"/>
                    </Trigger>-->
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The IsMouseOver Trigger works like intended. Why doesn't the DataTriggers work?

Note: I haven't tried using an enum before in a binding or trigger, but from what I've seen and understand this should work. At least it compiles and ReSharper doesn't nag!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `TemplateBinding` instead.

```
{TemplateBinding CurrentBackground}
```

In fact, you don't even need to use a `DataTrigger`. Just use a normal trigger instead.

```
<Trigger Property="CurrentBackground" ...
```

Comment: TemplateBinding didn’t work. Got this error: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.TemplateBindingExpression' to type 'System.Windows.Data.BindingBase'.". Using a Trigger gives this error: “’Red’ is not a valid value for property ‘CurrentBackground’.” Am I missing something else?

Comment: Actually, when using a Trigger the code compiles, runs and works, but in VS the XAML gets filled with blue squiggly lines saying there's an error. I guess I'll live with that for now...

Comment: That's weird. Have you tried rebuilding? Or closing Visual Studio and opening it again? What message do you get when you hover over the squiggly line?

Comment: I've tried rebuilding and restarting VS. The squiggly lines are still there, and the tooltip says “’Red’ is not a valid value for property ‘CurrentBackground’.”. As I said it compiles, runs and works like intended using Trigger, so I'm going to leave it like that for now.

Comment: I believe it's because your property is a `HexBackground`, and you are trying to set it to a `Brush`. Make sure that your resources (`{StaticResource HexRedHover}`) are the same **type** as your `CurrentBackground` property.